# Arduino Yun sketch not only working on usb connection

Tags: arduino, embedded, wifi, arduino-yun

I have the following problem:
Using Arduino 1.5.7 and Yun with OpenWrt 1.2 I can upload my sketch via USB and see my sketch working via serial monitor. However when I disconnect the usb connection then i can not connect the serial monitor anymore

> error: Unable to connect: is the sketch using the bridge?

and my sketch (Adding Data to Google Spreadsheet viaTemboo) is not working. I tried a example sketch (Bridge/Temboo/SendAnEmail) same result.

The sketch is only working when the Port is set to the USB connection dev/cu/usbmodem1411 (Arduino Yun).  What am I doing wrong (I'm quite new to the Yun)? I can connect to the Yun Configuration Page - so the Wifi part must be working.

Answer (score 1):

I work at Temboo.

Our examples assume that you're connecting to your Arduino board via USB. If you're not, you can make a simple modification to your sketch code so that it will run over Wifi. Here's a tutorial showing you what you need to do:

https://www.temboo.com/arduino/yun/serial-to-console

Please don't hesitate to get in touch if you have any further questions: support@temboo.com

Answer (score 0):

Sounds similar to what i experienced.
During boot the Arduino bootloader is looking for updates via the serial port. However if the RX ping is not connected to anything, it sees garbage data and sits there indefinitely waiting for an update that will never come. Just stick a 10k resistor across the RX and TX connections (ie: digital pins 0 and 1) or from RX to GND.